# Wimpy player cannot stream audio

Tags: html, audio-streaming, audio-player, wimpy

I am trying to integrate wimpy player on our website for **embedding audio player** for each audio file, and then adding them to a table.

here is the wimpy player doc: 
http://www.wimpyplayer.com/docs/options.defining.html

When I try to access a sample mp3 (in **javascript**) on the web from wimpy, I use:

```
return "< div data-wimpyplayer data-skin=\"/wimpy/wimpy.skins/038.tsv\" data-media=\"http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3\">< / div>";
```

This code embeds a div in my table and puts wimpy in one of the cells and it works (audio plays fine).

But, when I use:

```
return "< div data-wimpyplayer data-skin=\"/wimpy/wimpy.skins/038.tsv\" " + "data-media=\"http://localhost:9000/file/6d0f963f-d9cd-4136-b0bb-958aa881aef0?XX-SESSION=29bb3877-5e37-4e70-9516-045c5edca6c3\" > < / div > ";
```

It does not work. The player does not play any sound!

I opened both of the URLs:

```
http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/file/6d0f963f-d9cd-4136-b0bb-958aa881aef0?XX-SESSION=29bb3877-5e37-4e70-9516-045c5edca6c3
```

on my browser and both of them work, i.e. the inbuilt browser audio player is successfully able to stream audio.

Thoughts on why wimpy player might not be streaming the content?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting, to make your code easier for the rest of us to read!

Comment: Thanks leo. Formatted the two javascript snippets. Please let me know if there is any other problem.

Comment: I had to put spaces in the URLs (in the code and the example) as stackoverflow won't allow me more than 2 URLs. I made sure the URLs are working fine.

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to help you.  What's in your network tab?  What codecs are in use?  What's the difference between these two streams?

Comment: @Brad My aim is to play the audio which is streamed from my website (I saved the audio in bytes and streaming back in bytes). The GET on /file/:fileId in the second URL calls the stream REST api on my web server which returns the audio bytes. The first stream is just a sample mp3 file on some website (stephaniequinn). The streaming of the audio files works fine from both the URLs on the web browser. But, when I refer them in the wimpy 'data-media' attribute, just the sample one works, whereas the audio file on my web server doesn't get streamed.

Comment: Right, but what's the technical difference between the two?  What's in the headers?  Are there any errors on your network tab?

Comment: I used REST client to check if the their was a response headers difference. 

** From sample:  **
Date: Sun, 29 Jun 2014 20:29:24 GMT 
Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Jul 2009 21:15:18 GMT 
Accept-Ranges: bytes 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 1430174 
Content-Type: audio/mpeg 
ETag: "9ae493ac9110ca1:6b9"

**From my web server:  **
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
Content-Length: 1430174 
Content-Type: audio/mpeg

Comment: There isn't any error on the network tab. Response headers look the same. Even I am trying to understand if there is some difference in the way I am streaming the audio on my webserver.

Answer (score 0):

The data-media (the "media" player option) needs an extension in order to know what kind of media is being loaded.

So in your first example, you have dot mp3 at the end, which is a known "mp3" extension. Whereas on the later example there is no dot mp3.

You can add a psuedo-extension using a query string by tacking on a "?foo.mp3" to the end of the URL as:

```
http://localhost:9000/file/6d0f963f-d9cd-4136-b0bb-958aa881aef0?XX-SESSION=29bb3877-5e37-4e70-9516-045c5edca6c3?foo.mp3
```

Alternatively, you can use JSON in the "media" option and set the "kind" to "mp3" as:

```
"<div data-wimpyplayer data-skin=\"/wimpy/wimpy.skins/038.tsv\" " + "data-media=\"{\"file\":\"http://localhost:9000/file/6d0f963f-d9cd-4136-b0bb-958aa881aef0?XX-SESSION=29bb3877-5e37-4e70-9516-045c5edca6c3\", \"kind\":\"mp3\"}\"></div>";
```

or:

```
var mp3url = "http://localhost:9000/file/6d0f963f-d9cd-4136-b0bb-958aa881aef0?XX-SESSION=29bb3877-5e37-4e70-9516-045c5edca6c3"
return '<div data-wimpyplayer data-skin="/wimpy/wimpy.skins/038.tsv" data-media="{"file":"' + mp3url + '", "kind":"mp3"}"></div>';
```

See also:

- http://www.wimpyplayer.com/docs/pl.format.json.html
- http://www.wimpyplayer.com/docs/trackDataset.html
- The file named "media-playlist-embedded-json.html" in the "test" folder of the wimpy download ZIP package.